# How to sum up this series? $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1} B_n}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, bernoulli-numbers

I wonder what is the sum of this series?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1} B_n}{n}$$

where $B_n$ are Bernoulli numbers. Wolfram Alpha does not help.

P.S. As this series diverges I am interested in generalized summation. Mathematica fails to find the sum using Abel, Borel, Dirichlet, Cesaro and Euler's regularizations.

Comment: i would have guessed that borel should work (because it essentially kills the $n!$ in the asymptotic expansion)...have you tried it by hand? Mathematica is no always trustable in summing up divergent series...

Comment: @tired I do not know how to use it to obtain closed form. I do not need a numerical result...

Comment: i have no time today to get into details, but my first starting point would be to represent  the Bernoulli numbers by a contour integral and then trying the borel machine on this...

Comment: @tired I suspect the answer is $-2\gamma$. Need to be verified

Comment: @have you used my suggestion? then i'm confident that the euler constant will show up somewhere!

Comment: The general term is not bounded, so you have to tell us in which way you are extending the concept of "convergence" in this case.

Comment: @tired no, I used other considerations (non-rigorous).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a purely formal manipulation,
$$\frac{1}{e^t-1}-\frac{1}{t}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{B_n}{n!}t^{n-1} \tag{1}$$
leads to:
$$\frac{1}{e^{-t}-1}+\frac{1}{t}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1} B_n}{n!}t^{n-1}\tag{2}$$
hence by multiplying both sides by $e^{-t}$ and integrating them over $\mathbb{R}^+$,
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{t e^t}-\frac{1}{e^t-1}\right)\,dt = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1} B_n}{n}\tag{3}$$
but the LHS of $(3)$ [equals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant#Integrals) $\color{red}{-\gamma}$.

Comment: nice, borel summation  in action (+1)

Comment: This well can be the case!

Comment: By the way, why you have $\frac{1}{e^t-1}-\frac{1}{t}$ rather than simply $\frac{1}{e^t-1}$ in the first identity? Generating function is $\frac{1}{e^t-1}$.

Comment: @Anixx: the sum on the right starts at $n=1$, so we have to subtract a term.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks!

Comment: This is the reason why I needed this series, by the way: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/216252/expressing-trigonometric-functions-through-logarithms-and-inverse-trigonometric

Answer (score 4):

According to [this source](http://www.ma.rhul.ac.uk/~uvah099/Maths/Bernoulli2.pdf), the Bernoulli numbers satisfy the inequality $|B_{2n}| \ge \frac{(2n)!}{(2\pi)^{2n}}$. This means the sequnce $\frac{B_n}{n}$ is unbounded and the sum doesn't converge.

Answer (score 4):

The sum doesn't converge because the general term $B_n/n$ goes to $+\infty$ in absolute value, by the asymptotic approximation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number#Asymptotic_approximation).

Comment: The series has alternating sign.

Comment: @Anixx: The absolute value of the terms does not tend to $0$.

Comment: @Annix For a series to converge, the general term must tend to $0$ by definition of convergence of a series.

Comment: So what? The series has alternating sign. One can sum it up by gerneralization.

Comment: @Anixx That does not matter.

Comment: @Anixx: The most basic test for divergence says that if $|a_n|\not\to0$, then $\sum a_n$ cannot converge.

Comment: @Anixx So does the series $\sum (-1)^n n$. Alternating sign doesn't get you anything if the terms don't go to zero in absolute value.

Comment: @Anixx It may alternate, but does not go to zero. Regardless of the sign, the general term of the series **must** converge to zero for the series to converge: it is a necessary (not sufficient) condition.

Comment: @Clement C. how to sum it up using generalized summations?